# Calling a .NET core library from an electron app

Tags: .net-core, electron

My first post! I'm new at electron and I'm building an app that requires calling a dot net core library I have built.
I want the app to be cross-platform (that's why I used dotnet core). It looks like electron.NET and edge could potentially solve my problem but I'm wondering if there is a better solution to that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If it is only a .NET library you can use Edge.js and the native Electron.. 
https://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/

However, if you want your backend logic with C# and the API in .NET, you can use Electron.NET.
https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET
https://github.com/ElectronNET/electron.net-api-demos

Comment: Thank you! Edge should address my issue. Any perf issue I should be aware of?